# Get latest "group" of objects in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to get a queryset containing the latest "group" of items (by date).  Basically is there a prettier (and more efficent) way of doing this:

```
# get the latest set of news. It may or may not be today. 
# TODO: this seems ugly, find a better way
latest = Article.objects.latest('published')
latest_items = Article.objects.filter(published__year=latest.published.year,
                                                 published__month=latest.published.month,
                                                 published__day=latest.published.day)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it does some work twice and queries twice the db.

What you can do is query once with with `select_related` (to query only once the `published` data) and `order_by`:

```
articles = Article.objects.select_related('published').order_by('published')
```

And then use this queryset to do all your job:

```
def getLatest(queryset):
    latest = queryset.first()
    if latest == None:
        return

    for obj in queryset:
        if obj.published__year == latest.published__year and obj.published__month == latest.published__month and obj.published__day == latest.published__day:
            yield obj
        else:
            return
```